# Contact form 7 send data and redirect to other domain page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, contact-form-7

I have multiple Contact form 7 on wordpress and I want one form to redirect with send post data to other domain page.
I have added below code in functions.php for redirect my specific contact form,data was send successfully but page was not redirecting.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_form_action_url', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');
function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url($url)
{
global $post;
$id_to_change = 5240;
if($wpcf7_contact_form->ID === $id_to_change)
    return 'http://34.209.247.91:8069/page/register';
else
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of script that redirects you to another URL when the wpcf7mailsent event occurs.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
location = 'http://example.com/';
}, false );
</script>
```

Comment: you can add it to footer file

Comment: if i add this in footer then it will redirect all contact forms,but i need to only for a particular contact form,form id is 5240.